# Include ft2build.h in project on Linux

Tags: c++, include, freetype, juce

I've been trying to compile a JUCE project on Linux debian but a line is giving me an error:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

And stops compilation. How do I link to this file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I've had this issue before and found the straight answer this time.

**First, check if you have libfreetype installed.** I used:

```
pkg-config --cflags freetype2
```

**I do have the library installed,** so I got this as a result:

```
-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16
```

**If you don't have it installed**, do:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

And try the first command again.

**Then, link the header in your compilation.**
Using the ProJucer, this is easy, just paste `/usr/include/freetype2` in the *Header Search Paths* in the settings section.

Comment: Just a small note: `/usr/include/freetype2` should be added (without the `-I`)