# Can't find ft2build.h when building with Yocto SDK

Tags: c++, yocto, cairo, freetype

I'm trying to build file *DisplayControl.cpp* using SDK generated using bitbake based on my Yocto project. However, on this part:

```
    int DisplayControl::loadFonts()
    {
        FT_Library library;
        FT_Face face;
        FT_Init_FreeType(&library);

        //...

        return 0;
    }
```

Copiler returns following error:

```
In file included from /home/kek/Documents/Projects/Yocto/ice-misc/icedisplay/src/DisplayControl.hpp:15,
from /home/kek/Documents/Projects/Yocto/ice-misc/icedisplay/src/main.cpp:7:
> /opt/ice-sma/0.1/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/usr/include/cairo/cairo-ft.h:46:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
46 | #include <ft2build.h>
>       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I checked path specified in the error - **/opt/ice-sma/0.1/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/usr/include/cairo** and there was no ft2build.h file, but it is present at **/opt/ice-sma/0.1/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/usr/include/freetype2**. I also tried placing it manually in specified folder, but I would get the same error.

Freetype and Cairo libraries are included in *.bb* file:

```
DEPENDS = "alsa-lib gflags glog cairo freetype"
```

I tried following steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059150/include-ft2build-h-in-project-on-linux), but it was hard to apply since it was both local build (not Yocto) and it used JUCE framework so it was a little help.

So, how do I make the compiler aware that the file is there? I considered this to be some sort of linker issue, but I just can't find the cause.

Comment: The quick fix is to add `/usr/include/freetype2` (under the sysroot) to your include paths, but I wonder whether the cairo pkgconfig doesn't also specify that.

Comment: Yes, it indeed fixed my problem. I simply added `include_directories("/opt/ice-sma/0.1/sysroots/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/usr/include/freetype2")` to my **CMakeLists.txt**. However now it seems like linker is unable to find types defined in these headers e.g. `FT_Library` and `FT_Face`.

Comment: You should probably show your CMakeLists.txt then, that has nothing to do with Yocto.

Comment: Are you using the freetype and cairo-ft packageconfig files at all in your CMakeLists.txt? Those clearly describe what flags should be used.